# Formik Value not updated after get value form API

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-forms

I have an issue in updating input value after get value form external API in formik form in react. I get the value of the input field from API and the value sets to the input correctly. But my Issues in whenever I want to change the value in the input nothing happens and value not updated. I make a codesandbox sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-input-kddsoi?file=/src/App.js). I would be really appreciated If anyone can explain my problem.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [quick fix](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-input-forked-6xsfex), by adding onChange, and pointing initialValues to `value`:

```
initialValues={value}

onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
```